# How can I set two "default_realm" in krb5.conf

Tags: linux, active-directory, apache2, single-sign-on, kerberos

We got two active directories with different ending.

1. companya.de
2. companyb.com

Now we want to get access with both domains in a Single Sign On website. (Kerberos) 
The domains are forest trusted. We have one keytab from companya.de.
Our krb5.conf looks like that.

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = COMPANYA.DE
ticket_lifetime = 600
default_tkt_enctypes = RC4-HMAC
default_tgs_enctypes = RC4-HMAC

[realms]
COMPANYA.DE = {
kdc = 192.168.1.198 
default_domain = COMPANYA.DE
}

COMPANYB.COM = {
kdc = 192.168.2.78
default_domain = COMPANYB.COM 
}

[domain_realm]
.companya.de = .COMPANYA.DE
companya.de = COMPANYA.DE
.companyb.com = .COMPANYB.COM
companyb.com = COMPANYB.COM
```

VHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.companya.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory "/var/www/">
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Anwendungsname"
                KrbAuthRealms COMPANYA.DE
                KrbAuthRealms COMPANYB.COM
                KrbMethodNegotiate on
                KrbServiceName HTTP/apache-sso.companya.de
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/ssotest.keytab
                Require valid-user
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please post the Kerberos section of your httpd.conf

Comment: I really, really don't understand what you are trying to do. Is your `krb5.conf` taken from a Linux client that will access two different web servers? from one of the web servers? from a single web server that has two different IPs, and two different canonical DNS names, for two different sites?

Comment: You assert that the AD domains are "forest trusted", but how does that translate in terms of Kerberos "capath" http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#capaths >> I have seen cases where you have to hop from domain AAA to ROOT to BBB *(which requires defining* ROOT *by itself, plus the gory* [capath] *details)*

Comment: Our VHost (httpd.conf) looks like that @T-Heron

Comment: No we didnt tried it yet with "capath" @SamsonScharfrichter.